# Managing many separate docker hosts at remote sites

Tags: docker, containers, operations-orchestration

I'm looking for Docker orchestration software to manage containers running on a variety of remote hosts. These hosts are at the other end of a high latency and bandwidth restricted link, and are (and must remain) independent in operation from each other and from the link.

Based on my searching, most if not all of the container orchestration software out there is for managing many hosts in one data center, over local connections, and are generally set up to make it easy to distribute load and not care which specific machine is running a given container. An example of this is Shipyard (https://shipyard-project.com) which is built on Docker Swarm, and as far as I can tell, requires constant connection to a host, and doesn't have a specific method to pull images to specific hosts or deploying images to specific hosts except through the constraints.

My use case demands little to no bandwidth utilization to a given host except when needed for upgrades, troubleshooting, or deployment of new services. Ansible is a viable short term solution, but eventually we will need a UI for usability reasons, and some of the features out there like docker repository browsing, live log & stats viewing, and GUI for entering in docker run command parameters is very enticing.

I've found next to no mention of this type of environment from the big players like as Kubernetes and such. The question here is are there any existing projects that meet our needs, and if not, which are the closest so that modification may be a viable option. Developing our own is an option, but we need to explore other options first. Any paid/licensed services are viable options as well as open source.